# Can I edit my C++ project in Xcode (with jump to definition/auto completion) without building the project?

Tags: c++, xcode, ide

I'm working on a C++ project. My company has an internal build system which runs on Linux only. I'm not able to build the project on my mac. I would try to edit my C++ code with Xcode. I'd like to have at least 'jump to definition' and 'auto completion'. I created an empty project in Xcode and imported my files in there. It shows 'Symbol not found' when I tried to jump to definition. Is it possible to let Xcode parse my code without building the project?

Comment: Make sure you have all of your include paths set up correctly, this should work fine.

Comment: Did you consider using some other editor on your Mac, e.g. Emacs (with `etags` to manage symbols)?

Comment: @Xymostech I don't have all the header files included in my project as some of them are part of the build environment and not available on my mac. I cannot even jump to definition for a local variable.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thanks for this suggestion! I came from emacs and I realized I'm not an Emacs person.

Comment: Another possibility would be to install Linux on your Mac laptop, so to have a very similar environment on both  Mac laptop and office machine